# How to make a subscriber object with RAII properties?

Tags: rust, raii, borrow-checker, interior-mutability

I'm talking to some hardware over a link with kind of a publisher/subscriber model. In C++, I did subscriptions with RAII to remember to always unsubscribe, but I can't seem to get the ownerships/borrows right in rust.

Naively, this is something like what I would like to do. `send` and `receive` probably needs to be `&mut self`, so as I understand, `Subscription` needs mutable access to the `Transport`.

```
struct Transport;

impl Transport {
    pub fn send(&mut self, cmd: &str) { unimplemented!() }
    pub fn subscribe(&mut self, cmd: &str) -> Subscription {
        self.send("subscribe-with-params");
        Subscription { trans: &mut self }
    }
}

struct Subscription {
    trans: &mut Transport,
}

impl Drop for Subscription {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.trans.send("unsubscribe-with params");
    }
}

impl Subscription {
    fn receive(&mut self) -> &[u8] { /*blocking wait for data*/ }
}

fn test(t: Transport) {
    // Need to subscribe before command, as command might generate status messages
    let mut status_sub = t.subscribe("status-message");
    {
        let mut short_lived_sub = t.subscribe("command_reply");
        t.send("command");
        short_lived_sub.receive(); // Wait for ack
    }
    loop {
        println!("{:?}", status_sub.receive());
        /*processing of status */
    }
}
```

There are at least two problems here. One is how `Subscription` should keep some reference to it's "parent", the `Transport`, and another is the problem in `fn test` that I can't borrow `Transport` twice for two different subscriptions.

I have a feeling that I'm kind of asking the wrong question here, so maybe there's a good way of approaching this in a different way entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is problematic for your `Subscription` to hold a mutable reference to `Transport` because, as you discovered, you'll only be able to hold one at a time and you won't be able to do anything else with the transport in the meantime.

Instead, you can use an `Rc` (for shared ownership) and `RefCell` (for interior mutability):

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct TransportInner;

pub struct Transport {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<TransportInner>>,
}

pub struct Subscription { 
    trans: Rc<RefCell<TransportInner>>
}

impl TransportInner {
   pub fn send(&mut self, cmd: &str) { }
}

impl Transport {
   pub fn send(&mut self, cmd: &str) { 
       self.inner.borrow_mut().send(cmd)
   }

   pub fn subscribe(&mut self, cmd: &str) -> Subscription {
      self.send("subscribe-with-params");
      Subscription { trans: Rc::clone(&self.inner) }
   }
}

impl Drop for Subscription {
   fn drop(&mut self) {
      self.trans.borrow_mut().send("unsubscribe-with params");
   }
}
```

You can do this without splitting it into an inner and outer structure, but that would require the user to access the `Transport` via an `Rc` too, which could be unwieldy.

If you need this to work across threads, you should use `Arc<Mutex>` instead.